# Can we say anything about the order of the second largest eigen-value?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose we have a vertex-transitive graph ($G$) with degree $n$ and the number of vertices $N$.

Is it possible to say anything about the exact order of $\frac{1}{n-\lambda
_2}$ in terms of $N$ and $n$? where $\lambda_2$ is the second largest eigen value of the adjacency matrix of $G$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by exact order?

You cannot expect to get the exact value of your expression from $n$ and $N$ alone. Indeed there are cubic vertex transitive graphs of order $10$ that have a  differ value of your expression.

Do you have any other structural properties at hand?

For Cayley graphs (and in general for vertex transitive graphs) there are formulas for their eigenvalues so perhaps it makes sense for you to look in this direction.

Comment: By `exact order' I meant something like $\Theta(f(N,n))$ or $O(f(N,n))$ for some function $f$. The only structural property known is that the graph is vertex transitive.

Comment: You should then try to figure something out of the formula for the eigenvalues of a vt graph. Note that in general vertex transitive does not give you much of a difference. There are pairs of vertex transitive and not vertex transitive regular graphs with the same value of your expression.